# How do I split/divide a string in XSL?

Tags: xslt, split

This is my code and the only thing that is not working is that I am getting a time like this:

```
2012-03-24T15:00:00+00:00

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Event</th>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="Diary/Event">      
        <xsl:if test="@Classification = ''Some classification">
            <tr>
              <td><a href="http://www.example.com/somepage.php" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="@EventName"/></a></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@EventGroup"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@Time"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do you know what do I need to add in order to split the string of the time? Can you show an example please?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to show us a few important things: 1. A source XML document (minimal); 2. The exact wanted result; 3. Any rules for the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I use a template like this:

```
<xsl:template name="format_date">
        <xsl:param name="date" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat( substring($date, 7, 2),'.',substring($date, 5, 2), '.', substring($date, 1, 4), ', ', substring($date, 9, 2),':',substring($date, 11, 2),'h' )" />
    </xsl:template>
```

for a date string formatted like this: `20120324233001` to transform it into something like `25.03.2012, 08:47h`. You can adopt that for your specific string format.